# Python | mktime overflow error

Tags: python

I have been search all over the net and couldn't find an appropriate solution for this issue

```
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

The code that causes this exception

```
 t = (1956, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
 ser = time.mktime(t)
```

I would like to know the actual reason for this exception, some say that the date is not in a valid range but it doesn't make any sense to me, and if there's a range what it could be. Is it depends upon the system that we are using. Also would like to know a good solution for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [OSError: Errno 22 Invalid argument when using datetime.strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71680355/10197418)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`time.mktime` calls the underlying `mktime` function from the platform's C library. For instance, the above code that you posted works perfectly well for me on Mac OS X, although it returns a negative number as the date is before the Unix epoch. So the reason is that your platform's `mktime` implementation probably does not support dates before the Unix epoch. You can use Python's `datetime` module to construct a `datetime` object corresponding to the above date, subtract it from another `datetime` object that represents the Unix epoch and use the calculated `timedelta` object to get the number of seconds since the epoch:

```
from datetime import datetime
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
t = datetime(1956, 3, 2)
diff = t-epoch
print diff.days * 24 * 3600 + diff.seconds
```

**Update**: if you are using Python 2.7 or above, you could simply use `print diff.total_seconds()` as noted below in Chad Miller's comment.

Comment: print diff.total_seconds()

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer. Python 2.5 and 2.6 were far more prevalent in 2010 when I added this answer and `total_seconds()` is available from 2.7 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

python **time** module

> Although this module is always available, not all functions are
>   available on all platforms. Most of the functions defined in this
>   module call **platform C library functions** with the same name. It may
>   sometimes be helpful to consult the platform documentation, because
>   the semantics of these functions varies among platforms.
>
> The epoch is the point where the time starts, and is platform
>   dependent. For Unix, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC). To
>   find out what the epoch is on a given platform, look at
>   time.gmtime(0).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

**Windows 10:**

```
>>> time.gmtime(0)
time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)

>>> list((ix for ix in time.gmtime(0)))
[1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0]

>>> time.mktime(time.gmtime(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

**The C library function on windows 10 does not support times below a certain value.**