# Python Django overflow error mktime argument out of range

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am developing an application using Django.

In one of the models, I have a field `models.DateTimeField('date_of_birth')`.

I was trying to add few records from the django admin site. Few records were added without any problems. But, the record with a date of birth 1956-01-01 is causing '`Overflow error`' with the exception value '`mktime argument out of range`'.

Some Googling suggested that the mktime error comes when the date is earlier than the epoch(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518706/python-mktime-overflow-error)).

The work around suggested there was to use datetime to find the difference from the epoch and save it instead.

Is this not a bug? Is there any workaround instead of converting into the difference?

For the court records, I am using python 2.7, django 1.4.1 and MySQL 5.5 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: quick and dirty: create for each date-field an integerfield (day, month, year). On a birthday-field you normaly don't need any calculations - so no real date-object. Btw...you should use `models.DateField` instead of `DateTimeField`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the suggestion and it worked. Changing it to DateField didn't create any problems plus there are no errors for dates before epoch. I followed from the beginner tutorial and so used the DateTimeField while DateField would have sufficed me. This also reminds me to check all the available models

Comment: However, I am not closing my original question as I want to know how to deal with the DateTimeField as well.